# Is there any way that data can be inherited from one class to another?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I am trying to learn object oriented programming, and I got stuck at a problem. I have two class `A` and `B`. I am passing command line argument into class `A`, which then performs some computations and forms a 2d vector. (lets call the vector `data`)

I want class `B` to inherit class `A`.

So I was wondering is there any way, in which when default constructor of class `B` is called and it prints the contents of 2d vector `data`.

Sample code of what I have tried

```
class A
{
        
    public:
        vector<vector<string>>data;
        fstream file;
        string word, filename;
        A()
        {

        }
        A(string fileOpen)
        {
            file.open(fileOpen);
            while (file >> word)
            {
                
                vector<string>rowTemp={word};
                data.push_back(rowTemp);
            }
        }
        vector<vector<string>> getVector()
        {
            return data;
        }
};

class B:A
{
    public:
        B()
        {
            for(auto i:data)
            {
                for(auto j:i)
                {
                    cout<<j<<' ';
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 
    fstream file;
    string word, filename;
 
    file.open(argv[1]);
    string fileOpen=argv[1];

    A s(fileOpen);
    B c;
    return 0;
}
```

I basically want class B to have access 2d vector `data` so that I can perform further computations on it, while logic of computation remains inside class `B`.

Is there a way to do this?

Also, as you can see inside class `A` the default constructor is empty. But it is needed because without it, I received an error that default constructor of class `B` cannot be called. Is there a better way to write this? As having an empty default constructor looks bad.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. You can remove the file reading because that isnt essential for the question but prevents others from running your code

Comment: do you expect `B c;` to access members of `A s(fileOpen);` ? They are two unrelated objects

Comment: Just like member access for a `class` by default is `private`, so is inheritance. If you want to access the public members of a parent you need `public` inheritance. As in `class B : public A`.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you have classes A and B, and B inherits from A, then you don't (typically) have an explicit A instance, just a B one, which, as part of it, has an "embedded" instance of A.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing classes with objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how inheritance works, it is just not clear what you expected. The thing is: Members of a base class are always inherited. Their access can be limited, but they are still there.

Consider this simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
        
    public:
        int data = 42;
        A() = default;
        A(int value) : data(value) {}
        int getData() { return data; }
};

class B : A {
    public:
        B() {
            std::cout << A::data;         // ok
            std::cout << A::getData();    // ok
        }
};

int main(){ 
    B c;
    //std::cout << c.data; // error: data is private!
}
```

Output is:

```
4242
```

Because `B` does inherit the `data` member from `A`. Inside `B` you can access `data` either directly or via `getData` because both are `public` in `A`. However, because `B` inherits privately from `A` (thats the default inheritance for classes defined via `class`) you cannot directly access either `data` nor `getData` in `main`.

Furtermore, when you write:

```
A s(fileOpen);
B c;
```

Then `s` and `c` are two completely unrelated objects. I suppose you rather want:

```
B c{fileOpen};
```

and call `A`s constructor from the constructor of `B`:

```
B(const std::string& filename) : A(filename) {
     // now you can access A::data 
     // which has been initialized in 
     // constructor of A
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! this is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that constructor could be called like that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just to confirm, in ```B(const std::string& filename) : A(filename)``` the parameter of B is being inherited from class ```A```?

Comment: @alexderalu the parameter to `B`s constructor, `filename`, is forwarded to `A`s constructor